# CPanel detects Default Magento files as virus

Tags: magento-1.9, php, theme

We are facing an issue. Where Cpanel is detecting certain files as virus and blocking the site. The files detected as virus are:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/lib/Mage/Archive/Bz.php
/home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Event/Observer/Collection.php
/home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Measure/Illumination.php
/home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/View/Helper/Translate.php
```

We have currently changed back the permission of these files and site is up and working. We had done this thrice in past two days. Is it a template issue or issue from hosting end and what can be possible solution. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code just be safe. This maybe a false alram. Cpanel like other antivirus also checks its virus defination database. The code may resemble some virus signature.If the code is good, you can  exclude those files from Cpanel AV.